# How to write a cuda c argmax kernel like python does and let it decode one-hot matrix?

Tags: cuda

Like the title suggested.

Here is the code.

Where show_data() and get_data() are functions to display and inport data.

I'm not sure how to list through a one-hot matrix that is column major(which can fit into cublas functions), and decode it like python's argmax funtion.

I know I must have messed up the index inside the argmax kernel, not sure how I can fix it.

the data is like this:

[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]

the out put should be like:

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

```
#define IDX2C(i,j,ld) (((j)*(ld))+(i))

__global__ void argmax_kernel(float *data, float *dataout, int ld, int sd) {
    int stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    float temp = 0.0f;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;


    for (i = 0; i < ld; i++) {
        for (j = (tid + i*sd*stride); j < sd; j+= stride) {
            if (j = (tid + i*sd*stride)) {
                temp = data[j];
                dataout[i*sd*stride] = 1.0f;
            }
            else if (temp <= data[j]) {
                temp = data[j];
                dataout[i*sd*stride] += 1.0f;
            }
        }
    }
}

void argmax(float *data, float *dataout, int ld, int sd) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    float temp = 0.0f;

    for (i = 0; i < ld; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sd; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                temp = data[IDX2C(i, j, ld)];
                dataout[i] = 1.0f;
            }
            else if (temp <= data[IDX2C(i, j, ld)]) {
                temp = data[IDX2C(i, j, ld)];
                dataout[i] = dataout[i] + 1.0f;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    float *y_in, *y_out;
    float *d_yin, *d_yout;
    int rols_y = 20;
    int cols_y = 10;
    int size_y = rols_y*cols_y;
    char y_file_name[100] = "argmax.csv";


    y_in = (float*)malloc(size_y * sizeof(float));
    y_out = (float*)malloc(rols_y * sizeof(float));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_yin, size_y * sizeof(*y_in));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_yout, rols_y * sizeof(*y_out));

    get_ydata(y_in, y_file_name);
    show_data(y_in, rols_y, cols_y);

    cudaMemcpy(d_yin, y_in, size_y * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    argmax(y_in, y_out, rols_y, cols_y);
    show_data(y_out, rols_y, 1);


    dim3 dimBlock(256);
    int threadBlocks = (size_y + (dimBlock.x - 1)) / dimBlock.x;
    if (threadBlocks > 65520) threadBlocks = 65520;
    dim3 dimGrid(threadBlocks);

    argmax_kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_yin, d_yout, rols_y, cols_y);


    cudaFree(d_yin);
    cudaFree(d_yout);

    free(y_in);
    free(y_out);

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have outright errors in your kernel code such as this:

```
if (j = (tid + i*sd*stride))
```

but I wouldn't be able to explain what is going on more generally with your kernel code.  None of it makes sense to me.  I think the simplest thing to do is just to duplicate your host code in your kernel, converting only the outer loop in `ld` to be a grid-stride loop, which seems to be your desire. Here is an example:

```
 $ cat t23.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#define IDX2C(i,j,ld) (((j)*(ld))+(i))

__global__ void argmax_kernel(float *data, float *dataout, int ld, int sd) {
    int stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    float temp = 0.0f;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;


    for (i = tid; i < ld; i+= stride) {
        for (j = 0; j < sd; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                temp = data[IDX2C(i,j, ld)];
                dataout[i] = 1.0f;
            }
            else if (temp <= data[IDX2C(i, j, ld)]) {
                temp = data[IDX2C(i, j, ld)];
                dataout[i] += 1.0f;
            }
        }
    }
}

void argmax(float *data, float *dataout, int ld, int sd) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    float temp = 0.0f;

    for (i = 0; i < ld; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sd; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                temp = data[IDX2C(i, j, ld)];
                dataout[i] = 1.0f;
            }
            else if (temp <= data[IDX2C(i, j, ld)]) {
                temp = data[IDX2C(i, j, ld)];
                dataout[i] = dataout[i] + 1.0f;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    float *y_in, *y_out;
    float *d_yin, *d_yout;
    int rows_y = 20;
    int cols_y = 10;
    int size_y = rows_y*cols_y;
    float d_in[cols_y][rows_y] = {
{1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.}};

    y_in = (float*)malloc(size_y * sizeof(float));
    y_out = (float*)malloc(rows_y * sizeof(float));
    //transpose
    for (int r = 0; r < cols_y; r++)
      for (int c = 0; c < rows_y; c++)
        y_in[IDX2C(c,r,rows_y)] = d_in[r][c];
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_yin, size_y * sizeof(*y_in));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_yout, rows_y * sizeof(*y_out));

    cudaMemcpy(d_yin, y_in, size_y * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    argmax(y_in, y_out, rows_y, cols_y);
    for (int i = 0; i <  rows_y; i++)
      std::cout << y_out[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    dim3 dimBlock(256);
    int threadBlocks = (size_y + (dimBlock.x - 1)) / dimBlock.x;
    if (threadBlocks > 65520) threadBlocks = 65520;
    dim3 dimGrid(threadBlocks);

    argmax_kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_yin, d_yout, rows_y, cols_y);
    cudaMemcpy(y_out, d_yout, rows_y*sizeof(*y_out), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (int i = 0; i <  rows_y; i++)
      std::cout << y_out[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;


    cudaFree(d_yin);
    cudaFree(d_yout);

    free(y_in);
    free(y_out);

}
$ nvcc -o t23 t23.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t23
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

There are other things I don't understand here, like why you are using a `float` output data type to represent an index, but that doesn't seem to be the crux of your question.  I'm not suggesting this code is defect-free or optimal in any way, however it may be best to keep things simple at this point.

If you want to, you can probably simplify your host and device argmax functions like this:

```
$ cat t23.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#define IDX2C(i,j,ld) (((j)*(ld))+(i))


__host__ __device__ void argmax(float *data, float *dataout, int ld, int sd, int start, int inc) {
    for (int i = start; i < ld; i+=inc) {
        float valout = 1.0f;
        float temp = data[IDX2C(i, 0, ld)];
        for (int j = 1; j < sd; j++) {
            float val = data[IDX2C(i, j, ld)];
            if (temp <= val) {
                temp = val;
                valout += 1.0f;
            }
        }
        dataout[i]  = valout;
    }
}

__global__ void argmax_kernel(float *data, float *dataout, int ld, int sd) {
    int stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    argmax(data, dataout, ld, sd, tid, stride);
}

int main() {
    float *y_in, *y_out;
    float *d_yin, *d_yout;
    int rows_y = 20;
    int cols_y = 10;
    int size_y = rows_y*cols_y;
    float d_in[cols_y][rows_y] = {
{1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.},
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.}};

    y_in = (float*)malloc(size_y * sizeof(float));
    y_out = (float*)malloc(rows_y * sizeof(float));
    //transpose
    for (int r = 0; r < cols_y; r++)
      for (int c = 0; c < rows_y; c++)
        y_in[IDX2C(c,r,rows_y)] = d_in[r][c];
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_yin, size_y * sizeof(*y_in));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_yout, rows_y * sizeof(*y_out));

    cudaMemcpy(d_yin, y_in, size_y * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    argmax(y_in, y_out, rows_y, cols_y, 0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <  rows_y; i++)
      std::cout << y_out[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    dim3 dimBlock(256);
    int threadBlocks = (size_y + (dimBlock.x - 1)) / dimBlock.x;
    if (threadBlocks > 65520) threadBlocks = 65520;
    dim3 dimGrid(threadBlocks);

    argmax_kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_yin, d_yout, rows_y, cols_y);
    cudaMemcpy(y_out, d_yout, rows_y*sizeof(*y_out), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (int i = 0; i <  rows_y; i++)
      std::cout << y_out[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;


    cudaFree(d_yin);
    cudaFree(d_yout);

    free(y_in);
    free(y_out);

}
$ nvcc -o t23 t23.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t23
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

For other readers, I will point out that I don't consider this code to be a typical `argmax` implementation; it will not duplicate results for usual `argmax` functions on arbitrary data. But it should be usable with this kind of one-hot encoding data (only).